# Sort posts by name & show first letter only once in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've got a problem, I display posts in wordpress ordered by title in ascending order, but what I want is to display first letter of group of posts, I mean

```
A: Annanas
   Apple
   Almond
B: Banana
G: Grape
```

I don't know how to implement something like this in standard loop

```
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'publishers', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I'd be very happy if somebody can help me…

Take care and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea would be:

```
<?php 
$letter=' '; 
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'publishers', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php 
        $title=get_the_title(); 
        $initial=strtoupper(substr($title,0,1));
        if($initial!=$letter)
          {
          echo "<span>$initial : </span>";
          $letter=$initial;
          }
        echo $title;
        ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```